# Build minimal mesa/xorg for offscreen rendering

Tags: linux, opengl, xorg, mesa

I have managed to build a set of mesa libraries that together with a dummy xserver can run an OpenGL application on a machine with no GPU using openswr without relinking or changing any code in the application on a machine with a pre-existing Xorg installation. I'm using Linux on x64 (centos 7 to be specific)

The mesa build instructions I used are the following:
http://openswr.org/build-linux.html

Now I'm trying to set up a build process for this for machines without XOrg installed to start with for various reasons I won't go into detail on. Since there are some back and forth dependencies between the XOrg build process and mesa it becomes a dance involving building the right XOrg and mesa modules with the right parameters.

I have reached a point where I'm stuck.

It seems like mesa won't build gallium if dri is enabled. I.E if I remove the line --disable-dri from the mesa configure command line from the openswr example it won't work giving the following error.

> :configure: error: Xlib-based (Gallium) GLX cannot be built with DRI
>   enabled

On the Xorg side, using a mesa without dri, building xserver with the --disable-dri flag, the configure script works but the build fails with the following error:

> glxdriswrast.c:39:10: fatal error: GL/internal/dri_interface.h: No
>   such file or directory #include

(suggesting there are parts of xserver still referring to dri headers even if disabling it using --disable-dri).

Anyone have any idea what the right combination of flags to get all of this working? I'm not married to using openswr, llvmpipe is probably good enough for me in case it makes things easier.